# Limit result depending on sum of value

Tags: sql

I´ve been trying to automize a list of addresses in SQL. I have multiple addresses and quantities and i need only the addresses that will fulfill the quantity i need

For example:

I have a table with

```
Item A qty 20
Item B qty 5
Item C qty 23
```

And a table with addresses and units

```
Address 1  item A  15units
Address 2  item A  10units
Address 3  item A  10units
Address 4  item A  13units
```

The result should show only

```
Address 2  item A  10units
Address 3  item A  10units
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. In your example, what quantity of what item do you need ?

Comment: In the example I used the item A and I need 20 units. The table with the detailed of the addresses and units would be the second one. In this example, i want the result to be only the addresses that i should move/grab to fulffil the demand

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**.  Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues. Additionally, when replying to requests do so by updating the question, **not** with a comment.

Comment: @Yaco : OK for your need : 20 units of item A. Do you search for addresses whose sum quantities equals 20, or it may be greater then 20 ? Do you want to search among the addresses with a specific order, which order ?

Comment: @Edouard In this case, i dont have a problem if its not exactly 20 or more, or even an especific addres. The real world problem is, i have a list of items that are stored in racks and an amount of sales made. I would like to get a list of addresses so workers can lower the pallets for easier picking. The catch is not giving them a surpluss of pallets, because the addresses that are easier to pick are limited, so I dont want the all of the stock of X item.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your first table `sales` stores the sales made :

| Item | qty |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 23 |

and your second table stocks indicates the addresses of the stored items :

| Address | item | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 15 |
| 2 | A | 10 |
| 3 | A | 10 |
| 4 | A | 13 |

then you can select a subset of addresses so that the sum of the stored units is equal or greater than the quantity sold :

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT st.item
     , sa.qty AS sales_qty
     , array_agg(st.address) OVER w AS addresses
     , array_agg(st.units) OVER w AS units
     , sum(units) OVER w AS total_stored_units
  FROM sales AS sa
 INNER JOIN stocks AS st
    ON st.item = sa.item
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY st.item ORDER BY st.address)
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (item)
       item, unnest(addresses) AS address, unnest(units) AS units
  FROM list
 WHERE total_stored_units >= sales_qty
 ORDER BY item, total_stored_units ASC
```

Result

| item | address | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 15 |
| A | 2 | 10 |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wBEWIHEV)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Edouard!
I ended up using something like

```
WITH r AS 
(
SELECT 
  item,
  address,
  quantity, 
  sum(quantity)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY item
    ORDER BY quantity desc
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) as total_units
FROM st
GROUP BY 1,2,3 
)

SELECT *
FROM r
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
HAVING total_units <= qty_needed + avg(units)
ORDER BY units desc
```

I couldnt run your query in the bigquery console, but from it a re read some documentation of windows functions find this solution.

Again, thanks a lot!